# How to return image from php file set as img src

Tags: php

I am setting up a random image function but trying to prove the concept before handling the randomizer.

Right now I have a test.php file.  It contains:

```
<?php 
$img = 'http://example.com/img.jpg';
$fp = fopen($img, 'rb');


header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($img));

fpassthru($fp);
exit;
?>
```

And then in another html file I have `<img src="test.php">`

The goal is just to return the image.  The image url works is right, and test.php returns a 200.  But the image just shows the little broken image icon.

I have also tried `readfile()` with no luck.

I am just trying to show this image.

Comment: use a path and not a url. edit: if that v V v isn't alllowed

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled on your server?

Comment: Yes, allow_url_fopen is enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`filesize` does not work on HTTP URLs. The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) say:

> This function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

However, the [HTTP wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) does not support the `stat` function. Because of this, you send a wrong `Content-Length` header and the HTTP response cannot be interpreted by your browser.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Load the image into memory and use `strlen`:

   ```
   $image = file_get_contents('http://example.com/img.jpg');

   header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
   header("Content-Length: " . strlen($image));
   echo $image;
   ```
2. Use the [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) variable to read the remote response's `Content-Length` header:

   ```
   $img = 'http://example.com/img.jpg';
   $fp = fopen($img, 'rb');

   header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
   foreach ($http_response_header as $h) {
       if (strpos($h, 'Content-Length:') === 0) {
           header($h);
           break;
       }
   }

   fpassthru($fp);
   ```

Comment: Beautifully written answer helmbert!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use some of the various built in functions for generating / manipulating images - in the case of the code below it is for a png but similar functions exist for jpg,gif and bmp.

Using a url as the filepath relies upon that setting being enabled by your host ( on dev obviously you control whether it is enabled or not )

Using these functions also gives you the possibility to add your own text at runtime, combine images and all sorts of other cool things.

```
<?php

    if( ini_get( 'allow_url_fopen' ) ){
        $imgPath='http://localhost/images/filename.png';
    } else {
        $imgPath=realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/filename.png' );
    }

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
    imagesavealpha($image,true);
    imagealphablending($image,true);
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
?>
```